# CakePHP - allow for formatting of text inputs

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, markup, text-formatting

I'm building a CakePHP (3.0) app that will allow users to submit proposals.  These proposals consist of many different text input fields, and the app uses a MySQL database.  I need to allow for formatting of text when users submit their proposals.  That is, if a user types out a paragraph in an input box, they need to be able to highlight, bold, italicize, etc. their text, then submit it, and the formatting needs to remain.

I know there are tools/languages out their that allow for text formatting, such as Markdown, but I'm not sure how to integrate these with CakePHP or how to set up my database so that it can accept that kind of input.  Does anyone have experience with this or know of a tutorial, explanation, etc. that achieves this or a similar result?

Comment: You  have to use [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) for this problem. I use [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) .

Comment: Thanks!  That at least gives me an idea of what to search now.  Have you used tinyMCE with CakePHP before?

Comment: yea. I was use this [plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE)

Comment: Thanks!  Do you happen to know if it's compatible with CakePHP 3.0?

Comment: I dont know . But you can use this directly without plugin